# Json not being deserialized in ASP.Net MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I am having a very difficult time figuring out why my JSON is not being correctly deserialized in the MVC controller. The controller action is here:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(MessageRequest messageRequest)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            Task.Run(() => _emailService.SendMessageAsync(messageRequest));

            return Ok();
        }
```

And the MessageRequest model and the definitions for its members are here:

```
    public class MessageRequest
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A message is required.")]
        [DataMember(Name="message")]
        public MessagePayload Payload { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="origin")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "An origin is required for every message.")]
        public Origin Origin { get; set; }
    }

    public class MessagePayload
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "from")]
        public EmailAddress From { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "to")]
        public IEnumerable<EmailAddress> To { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "cc")]
        public IEnumerable<EmailAddress> Cc { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "bcc")]
        public IEnumerable<EmailAddress> Bcc { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "subject")]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "content")]
        public Content Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class Origin
    {
        [Required]
        [DataMember(Name = "origin_url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataMember(Name = "origin_message_id")]
        public string MessageId { get; set; }
    }
```

I can't figure out why the JSON post request below isn't deserializing properly.

```
{
   "message":{
      "from":"gumby@jacketforce.ca",
      "to":[
         {
            "name":"Bubba Gump",
            "email":"bubba.gump.dm@gmail.com"
         }
      ],
      "subject":"A new mail for mr bubbles",
      "content":{
         "html":"<html><h1>This is definitely html</h1></html>",
         "text":"This is a text email instead"
      }
   },
   "origin":{
      "origin_url":"http://requestb.in/bin",
      "origin_message_id":"MESSAGE_ID_DOESNT_MATTER"
   }
}
```

I have tried adding and removing **DataContract** and **DataMember** attributes, the **FromBody** attribute, removing the serialization attributes and changing the names of the properties to what they are named in the JSON. One morning I started work and almost magically, everything worked after changing nothing(nothing obvious anyway). As far as I can tell, the JSON I am sending is perfectly formed according to the model specifications provided. Sometimes I get a completely null action parameter, while other times I'll get a non-null parameter that has all of its properties null instead.

Why can't I get my JSON to be reliably deserialized into one of my object types?

Comment: There are some bits missing on the question, like EmailAddress and Content

Comment: `[DataMember]` is ignored unless [`DataContract`] is applied to the type.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx): *Apply the DataMemberAttribute attribute in conjunction with the DataContractAttribute to identify members of a type that are part of a data contract. One of the serializers that can serialize data contracts is the DataContractSerializer.*